# Why does R density function return nonzero values outside the interval [from, to]?

Tags: r, kernel-density

I have entered into the R code of the `density` function, and I have noticed the following strange lines:

```
lo <- from - 4 * bw
up <- to + 4 * bw
```

To my understanding, they mean that the density is estimated on the interval `[from - 4*bw, to + 4*bw]` instead of `[from, to]`.

To really understand what is going on, I have created a `densityfun` function, which copy-pastes the code of `density`, except at the end in order to return a function (you can find the R code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/polmath/densityfun/blob/master/densityfun.R)). Then I get the following:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rbeta(10000, 0.5, 0.5)
f <- densityfun(x, from = 0, to = 1)
f(-0.01) # 1.135904
```

Surprise: `f(-0.01)` is nonzero! 
It also implies that the integral of `f` on `[0, 1]` is not `1`:

```
integrate(f, 0, 1) # 0.8787954
integrate(f, -0.1, 1.1) # 0.997002
```

So why is the `density` function written that way (is it a bug?), and what could I do to avoid this behaviour (to have `f(-0.01) = 0` in this example) without loosing any mass on `f` (to have `integrate(f, 0, 1)` approximately equal to `1` in this example)?

Thanks!

---

EDIT: I have changed a bit the values used in the example.

Comment: The "why" is explained in the documentation of the `from`, `to` and `cut` arguments. It is not a bug. I think for obvious reasons, getting good estimates for a density estimate of a beta distribution just below 0 will be difficult without some tweaking. Keep in mind that `density` is _just an estimate_. Adjusting the bandwidth brings the estimates down to zero faster, but that might not be desirable for other reasons. Otherwise, you can always wrap the function in something that hard codes values outside a particular range.

Comment: why did you use `rule=2`?

Comment: @LegalizeIt Indeed, that is probably more to the point than my ramblings.

Comment: @joran I believe your ramblings are more relevant here. polmath, note also that the documentation recommends setting `bw = "SJ"`.

Comment: @joran: no the point I raise is not in the documentation. What the documentation says is the following: the `from` and `to` arguments are the left and right-most points of the grid at which the density is to be estimated; the defaults are `cut * bw` outside of `range(x)`. In my example you can add `cut = 0` when the `densityfun` function is called, it won't change the result. And yes `density` is just an estimate, but it is often desirable that estimates satisfy some properties or fullfill some constraints (like being of integral 1 for a density estimate for instance).

Comment: @LegalizeIt: I use `rule = 2` to avoid getting `NA` when `approxfun` is called. But since I specify `yleft = 0` and `yright = 0` in the call to `approxfun`, I realize I don't need to give a value to `rule`.

Comment: @Roland: Indeed setting `bw = "SJ"` is recommended, but I don't think it relates to my question. I have changed a bit the values in the example I give: you can test that with `bw = "SJ"` the problem persists.

Comment: You wrote "Why is the density function written that way?", which I took to mean "Why is density defining lo and up this way?" and the reason is as it says in the docs: "This allows the estimated density to drop to approximately zero at the extremes.". Your complaint appears to be that using the defaults the estimate does not drop to 0 fast enough for your tastes. Hence my comment that the end points of a beta distribution are sort of an edge case estimation-wise. If you want a _general purpose_ density estimator to work you will need to hand tweak the results yourself.

Comment: @joran: you are referring to the documentation of the `cut` argument; but in the code if `from` and `to` are not missing, `cut` is not used at all. And `lo` (resp. `up`) is set to `from - 4*bw` (resp. `to + 4*bw`). I would better understand something like `lo <- from - cut*bw` and `up <- from + cut*bw`. Moreover the default value of `cut` is `3`, while for `lo` and `up` we have a (hard-coded) `4`.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. I agree it's a little confusing as to why it would move the end points apart twice when you specify `from` and `to` and only once otherwise. But the docs don't claim that `cut` will be used if `from` and `to` are specified.

Comment: @joran: I realize after your last but one comment it may be worth to give some motivation. In fact I used the beta distribution to have a reproducible example; but the question comes from the real data I use, whose values are non-negative, and whose bandwidth estimate is quite high compared to the range of the data. It makes a significant part of the mass of the density estimate below 0 (even when I set `cut = 0` as explained above).

Comment: @joran: my point is that there is no way to have `f(-0.01) = 0`, even when playing with the parameters of the function. And I am wondering if it is done on purpose (why would this `4` be hard-coded otherwise?) -for some statistical or computational reason-, or if this is some kind of bug or mistake (which I would find surprising).

Comment: I think your expectations are unreasonable for the pathological case of a true density that goes to infinity at 0 and 1. Most cases would involve a function going to zero in either direction smoothly, and density is written to handle most cases (which seems sensible to me). But in any case your claim is not correct: try `from = 0.2` and `to = 0.8` to compensate for the function moving the endpoints out. When I do that I get `f(-0.01) = 0`.